# What does Hume's "customary connection" between objects mean?

Tags: epistemology, hume

David Hume writes "All belief of matter of fact or real existence is derived from some object, present to the memory or the senses, and a customary conjunction between that and some other object."  What does Hume mean here?  In what way, if any, does this view differ from the ordinary conception of how we understand knowledge of cause and effect?

Comment: See [Hume : Causal Inference](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hume/#CauInfCriPha) : "Causal inferences are the only way we can go beyond the evidence of our senses and memories. In making them, we suppose there is some connection between present facts and what we infer from them. If the connection is established by an operation of reason or the understanding, it must concern either *relations of ideas* or *matters of fact*. Hume argues that the connection can't involve relations of ideas."

Comment: "Since we're determined— *caused* —to make causal inferences, then if they aren't “determin'd by reason”, there must be “some principle of equal weight and authority” that leads us to make them. Hume maintains that this principle is *custom* or *habit*: 'whenever the repetition of any particular act or operation produces a propensity to renew the same act or operation … we always say, that this propensity is the effect of *Custom'. (EHU 5.1.5/43) It is therefore custom, not reason, which “determines the mind … to suppose the future conformable to the past” (Abstract 16).

Comment: What is the citation for the Hume quote?